# AngularJS Array of Promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Can anyone help me with some Angular promises? I have the following functions that should take in an array of file objects, iterate over them, and upload each one. During each iteration, a promise object is pushed to an array of `promises`. Within my `upload` function I have a `cycle` function with a `.then()` attached, which should not be called until all the promise objects have resolved. I think my code looks correct, but it's not working right. The images upload, but `cycle(files).then()` is being called immediately, rather than once the `promises` array resolves.

```
function upload(files) {
    var uploadCount = files.length;
    function cycle(files) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            promises.push(deferred);
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/photos.json',
                file: file
            }).success(function(){
                $scope.progressCurrentCount += 1;
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        };
        return $q.all(promises);
    };

    cycle(files).then(function(result) {
        if(uploadCount > 1) {
            $scope.lastAction = 'uploaded ' + uploadCount + ' photos';
        } else {
            $scope.lastAction = 'uploaded ' + uploadCount + ' photo';
        }
        $scope.showSuccessModal = true;
        $scope.uploading = false;
        $scope.failedUploads = [];
        $scope.newPhotos = {
            token: $scope.token,
            files: undefined
        };
        photoUploadBtn.removeClass('disabled');
    })
};
```

**Final working code***

Rather than setting `var deferred = $q.defer();` pushing `deferred.promise` into the `promises` array, and then resolving `deferred` in my `.success()` callback, which wasn't working, I just push my `Upload.upload()` function without the `.success()` callback into `promises`, and then pass that to `$q.all()`, which does all the lifting.

```
function upload(files) {
    var uploadCount = files.length;
    function cycle(files) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var promise = Upload.upload({
                url: '/photos.json',
                file: file
            });
            promises.push(promise);
        };
        return $q.all(promises);
    };

    cycle(files).then(function(result) {
        if(uploadCount > 1) {
            $scope.lastAction = 'uploaded ' + uploadCount + ' photos';
        } else {
            $scope.lastAction = 'uploaded ' + uploadCount + ' photo';
        };
        $scope.showSuccessModal = true;
        $scope.uploading = false;
        $scope.failedUploads = [];
        $scope.newPhotos = {
            token: $scope.token,
            files: undefined
        };
        photoUploadBtn.removeClass('disabled');
        getPhotos(q);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must push a promise, not a deferred, to the `promises` array:

```
promises.push(deferred.promise);
```

It helps if you think about it like this:

- the promise is a read-only object you want to return to the consumers
- deferred is the modifier of that read-only promise and you want to keep it for yourself

Comment: Thanks, that was most of the solution I needed! I also came upon [this article](https://www.jonathanfielding.com/combining-promises-angular/), which made me realize that I should approach things slightly differently. I'll put my final code in my post above.